# SQL Call function foreach row on every record in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables; Table1 (name, latitude, longitude) with 400 records in and Table2 (name, latitude, longitude) with 10,000 records in.

I want to find all records in Table2 that are physically close to the 400 records in Table1. (excluding all the 400 records in Table1).

I have a function that works out the distance between two records. My problem is in SQL I can't figure out how to run it for every record in Table1, on every record in Table2. I am calling my function as below;

```
dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(item1.lat, item2.lat, item1.long, item2.long) < 0.150
```

This gets the distance between the two coordinates and will only return the ones if it is within 150 metres. It works fine but I am struggling with running it for each record in Table1 over every record in Table2.

Any pointers would be greatly appriciated! I think this is fairly simple to do in SQL but my experience is lacking.

Comment: What does the fnCalcDistanceKM function do?

Comment: What type of function is this? A scalar function? Table valued function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the [cross join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) operator:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table1 T1 
    cross join Table2 T2 
WHERE 
    dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(T1.lat, T2.lat, T1.long, T2.long) < 0.150
```

Comment: @RachelAmbler Good point! Since we have that function, I guess `cross apply` will work better in this case, especially on big recordsets ...

Answer (score 2):

Select from both tables:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Table1 as item1,
Table2 as item2
WHERE dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(item1.lat, item2.lat, item1.long, item2.long) < 0.150
```

Comment: Yes.  Cross product.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to change the datatypes of the tables? Since you're using SQL 2008+, you can use the GEOGRAPHY datatype and store lat/lon in one column, then easily do a comparison between the two using a CROSS JOIN.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.loc, t2.loc.STDistance(t1.loc) AS distance  
FROM Table2 t2
CROSS JOIN Table1 t1
WHERE  t2.loc.STDistance(t1.loc) < 150
```

Or with your current dataset, maybe:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.latitude, t2.longitude
    , POINT(t2.latitude & ' ' & t2.longitude) AS thePoint
    , (POINT(t2.latitude & ' ' & t2.longitude)).STDistance(POINT(t1.latitude & ' ' & t1.longitude)) AS distance
FROM Table2 t2
CROSS JOIN Table1 t1
WHERE  (POINT(t2.latitude & ' ' & t2.longitude)).STDistance(POINT(t1.latitude & ' ' & t1.longitude)) < 150
```

This will be slow if you don't have an index on the locations, but it will be very accurate. And you won't have to run an extra function on every row. You'll have to test the time.

Comment: The extras in the SELECT are merely for illustration. You can remove those if you don't need them and significantly speed up the operation.